# Is there a place to ask about copyright/patent as it pertains to 3rd party product accessories?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation, legal, copyright

I'm developing a product that is an add-on to some existing item.  Someone was giving me advice and was vaguely warning me about legal issues since my product depends on the other product to function.  Let's use an example of a fancy headset that works specifically with an iPhone.  Does the headset maker have to get permission from Apple?

This is the kind of question I need help with.  Don't know where to ask.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/). We have quite a few questions on [copyright](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright) and [patents](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/patents).

Be careful to not ask for legal advice. We're not fans of that; the question would be closed as "off topic".

Comment: err... riddle me this.  What's the difference between asking a legal question and asking for legal advice?

Comment: @bcsteeve "Legal advice" often requires a lawyer/solicitor. However a "legal question" can cover many scopes.

Comment: @bcsteeve For us, legal advice generally pertains to a specific, personal case, whereas a general legal question can be applied in many different situations.

Comment: @bcsteeve "will i get sued for making a headset with x Apple specific features?" asks for legal advice; "what is the relevant case law for OEM manufacturers of Apple headsets?" isn't. Think of it as "what should I do" (opinion) versus "what is the existing law" (objective fact).